# Mutex | Spinlock | ??? in LKM

Tags: c, linux, kernel, kernel-module

What should I be using if (on a multicore system) I wanted to make a kernel module function be ran only by one core at a time? Said in other words, avoid two cores running the same function at the same time; aka, one of the cores should wait for the other one to finish running the function.

Mutex? Spinlock? Something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use variants of spinlock() i.e raw_spin_lock_irqsave(), raw_spin_lock_irqrestore() (https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/include/linux/spinlock.h#n188), not mutex() cause they're sleep-able, so they might wake up on some other CPUs. And spinlock will make sure your code won't be executed by other cores. It's been very well documented in Linux kernel tree at Documentation/spinlock.txt (https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/Documentation/spinlocks.txt).

Answer (score 3):

Since rakib has already suggested using spinlocks, I'm going to explain a bit more about how to use them.

After setting up the spinlock, e.g.

```
static DEFINE_SPINLOCK(your_lock);
```

You can simply wrap the contents of your function with spin_lock_irqsave/spin_lock_irqrestore, e.g.:

```
static void function_to_protect()
{
    unsigned int flags;
    spin_lock_irqsave(&your_lock, flags);
    /* function body here */
    spin_lock_ireqrestore(&your_lock, flags);
}
```

If you know for sure that your lock won't be touched by an interrupt handler, you can elect to use the lighter weight functions spin_lock and spin_unlock and omit the flags variable.

Reference: https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/Documentation/spinlocks.txt